# Generating background-style in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

In Wordpress, I try to set the background of a div dynamically by using the post-thumbnail url in a style parameter. I put the style-parameter in a variable, named style.
If I echo $style directly, it outputs:

```
style="background: url("http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/potloden_120px.png") cover no-repeat;"
```

But if I echo $style in the div, like so:

```
<div class="column" <?php echo $style; ?>>
```

I get the following output:

```
<div class="column" style="background: url(" http:="" localhost="" test="" wp-content="" uploads="" 2012="" 11="" potloden_120px.png")="" cover="" no-repeat;"="">
```

Does anyone now what causes this? How should I adept my syntax for this to work?

Comment: localhost not working on web please change url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this in your code

```
<div class="column" style="background: url('<?php echo $image; ?>') cover no-repeat;">
```

Add URL inside single quote.This will evaluate variable in proper format.

```
url('<?php echo $image; ?>')
```

output will be

```
<div class="column" style="background: url('http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/potloden_120px.png') cover no-repeat;">
```

**Tips** Use single quotes so that you don't have to escape the double quotes (when using echo),

Comment: oh man, I missed that. feel kinda stupid. One of those days I guess... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have checked, Please put below code in to your wordPress template and check it.

```
<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>

<div id="post" class"your-class" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>')">
<p>text demo</p>
</div>
```